# NGRX Why reducer does not react to action dispatched from effect?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

There is a feature implemented with NGRX that consists of

**two actions**

```
export class UpdateWordListAction implements Action {
    static readonly TYPE = 'UPDATE_WORD_LIST';
    readonly type = "UPDATE_WORD_LIST";
    constructor() {};
}
export class WordListLoadedSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly words: Word[];
    static readonly TYPE = 'WORD_LIST_LOADED_SUCCESS';
    readonly type = "WORD_LIST_LOADED_SUCCESS";
    constructor(words: Word[]) {};
}
```

**client**

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateWordListAction());
```

**effect**

```
@Effect()
testEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(UpdateWordListAction.TYPE), 
   tap(console.log), // Runtime: UpdateWordListAction {type: "UPDATE_WORD_LIST"}
   switchMap(() => this.wordService.getWordList()), 
   tap(console.log),  // Runtime: (2) [{…}, {…}]
   map(words => new WordListLoadedSuccessAction(words)),
   catchError(() => EMPTY));
```

**and reducer**

```
export const reducers = combineReducers<AppState, any>({
    words(state = initialAppState.words, action: WordListLoadedSuccessAction) {
        console.log(action); // Never reached!
        return action.words;
    }
  });
```

I don't understand why this reducer does not work. Please help to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Any reason you're not using modern NgRx methods like `createAction` and `createReducer`? The latter allows you to use `on` for easy action-reducer setup.

Comment: Is your reducer registered in the appropriate module?